# Предоставить root для Netbeans

Tags: php, linux, netbeans

Всем привет , работаю в netbeans , но когда php создает или редактирует файлы он ставит привилегии только для www , а так как Netbeans запущен не под рутом то сами понимаете...
Возможно ли предоставить Netbeans root привилегии на ubuntu ?
Я могу его запустить от рута , но тогда откроется другой Netbeans , не - тот же самый ,в котором у меня проект и все настройки.
Как быть ? Прошу совета
Спасибо.

Comment: `когда php создает или редактирует файлы он ставит привилегии только для www`- Как такое возможно? Какие файлы он редактирует? Зачем их потом править в Neatbeans? `chown`  вам в помощ ;)

Comment: Вы наверное правите код пряма в `/var/www/html`? Это, не очень хорошая идея. Как вариант можно сделать сим линк. `ln -s /your/project/folder /var/www/html`. только сначала удалите  `/var/www/html`

Comment: есть около 30 файлов , которые php создает по образцу , в этом образце я забы подправить <title> страницы))) И теперь вот думаю , вручную сменить титлы и поправить в образце , не создавать же заново через админку все эти 30 файлов

Comment: точнее создает то он 1 файл , но более 30 уже создал

Comment: возможно , когда у тебя linux и php стоит как модуль apache2

Comment: Ещё один небольшой совет. Если вы генерирует статические файлы из админки то есть смысл посмотреть на генераторы статических сайтов https://www.staticgen.com/. Сам пользовался middleman очень легко и быстро можно перегенерировать весь сайт с новым дизайном.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас 2 варианта

**Скопироват свой netbeans профиль руту**

`sudo cp -R /home/youruser/.netbeans /root/`

и потом запустить netbeans из под рута

**Поменять владельца файлов**

`sudo chown  youruser -R /path/to/files`

поправить потом

`sudo chown  www-data -R /path/to/files`

Answer (score 0):

Нормально настроить virtualhost в apache и не страдать фигней с root и netbeans
Создаешь в своей домашней папке папку www, настраиваешь работу apache от твоего пользователя
https://interface31.ru/tech_it/2015/06/nastraivaem-veb-server-na-baze-apache-v-debian-ubuntu-server.html

https://dyrik.ru/linux/ustanovka-apache2-mpm-itk-v-ubuntu-16-04.html